# Oracle 11gXE : ошибка при загрузке системных таблиц , вьюшек и прочих объектов БД

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Здравствуйте. В данный момент я пытаюсь создать новую базу данных поверх существующей. Об ограничениях версии XE я наслышан и не раз , но все равно было грех не попробовать создать новую БД под другим именем экземпляра (oracle_sid=ORCL) в качестве тренинга. Что я собственно и сделал. Потом я решил попробовать сделать запрос к системным таблицам БД экземпляра ORCL , но вот ошибка , что данной таблицы не существует и я не понимаю почему:

```sql
select * from DBA_TABLESPACES;

select * from DBA_TABLESPACES
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Вот я и подумал , что если перезагрузить службу Oracle , которая запускает экземпляр ORCL. Я так и сделал , но проблема не исчезла. Поэтому дальше я попробовал запустить скрипт , который как я понимаю создаёт все стандартные системные объекты , таблицы , вьюшки и.т.д. Он называется catproc.sql. Я его запустил. Но некоторые объекты БД при записи оказались инвалидными. Опять же почему-то с ошибками созданы были некоторые объекты. Поэтому в надежде , что все объекты перепишутся , решил запустить заново этот скрипт , но случилось следующее:

```
SQL> @C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\catproc.sql
        DOC>######################################################################
        DOC>######################################################################
        DOC>    The following PL/SQL block will cause an ORA-20000 error and
        DOC>    terminate the current SQLPLUS session if the user is not SYS.
        DOC>    Disconnect and reconnect with AS SYSDBA.
        DOC>######################################################################
        DOC>######################################################################
        DOC>#
```

А мне нужно как бы , чтобы удалить всё , что создано было скриптом catproc.sql , чтобы им же при повторном его запуске все системные объекты перезаписать заного. Как это сделать ? И что я должен сделать , чтобы все системные объекты , вьюшки , таблицы записались без ошибок ? Прошу вас скажите , а то я вообще не знаю куда копать.

Comment: А вы под SYS подлкючились к БД ?

Comment: @Mike , ну да. sqlplus sys as sysdba . Вы это имеете в виду ? Или к sys подключаться по другому надо ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребята.

Оказывается вот оно какое решение. Обычно , если какой-то скрипт при полноценном создании БД с системным "добром" ты запустил не последовательно по инструкции (Например , сначала catproc.sql запущен , когда надо было сначала создать каталог объектов с помощью скрипта catalog.sql , а уже потом запустить скрипт catproc.sql) , тогда для очистки БД от этого "добра" я запустил catupgrd.sql , который сбрасывает всё это путём апгрейда версии БД на ту же самую, чтобы можно было бы эти скрипты запустить в правильном порядке без вылета ошибки ORA-20000. Однако есть одно но. Чтобы версию вашего Oracle апгрейдить с той же версии на ту же самую , нужно чтобы при обновлении она отличалось номером релиза иначе при следующем запуске скрипта обновления catproc.sql будет вылетать всегда ORA-20000. Это не очень удобный способ , но таким образом хотя бы можно несколько раз стирать содержимое процедур , пакетов , и прочих видов объектов и фичей системы Oracle текущей версии по несколько раз вместо того , чтобы тотально стирать всю БД и инстанс , чтобы пересоздавать заново добавить версию продукта в папку product и переносить свою текущую БД в неё , так ещё и предварительно менять значение пути в переменной среды ORACLE_HOME.